# Convert into pure numeric form

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a data frame `x` having multiple (here 2) columns:

```
    1,324 RM     342 K
    2,453 DR   2,451 G
1,232,673 RM   3,421 L
      324 RM   7,543 S
```

I want to get rid of commas and alphabetic characters (e.g. RM, K, G). So, I expect a data frame:

```
    1324      342
    2453     2451
 1232673     3421
     324     7543
```

Can someone suggest a right way to do it? As the data is large, the right way matters.

Answer (score 1):

When there are multiple columns, we could loop each column using `lapply` and remove the non-numeric elements with `gsub`.  The result of `lapply` will be a 'list', which can be assigned back to the original dataset.  The idea of using `[]` is to keep the structure of the original 'data.frame' intact.  Suppose, if we do `x <- lapply(x,...)` then the modified 'x' will be a list of 2 instead of 'data.frame' with 2 columns.  In the `gsub`, we select all the non (`^`) numeric (`0-9`) elements and replace it with `''`.

```
 x[] <- lapply(x, function(y) as.numeric(gsub('[^0-9]+', '', y)))
 x
 #    Col1 Col2
 #1    1324  342
 #2    2453 2451
 #3 1232673 3421
 #4     324 7543
```

#### data

```
 x <- structure(list(Col1 = c("1,324 RM", "2,453 DR", "1,232,673 RM", 
 "324 RM"), Col2 = c("342 K", "2,451 G", "3,421 L", "7,543 S")), 
.Names = c("Col1", "Col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-4L))
```

Comment: Beat me to it. :) What are the trailing empty brackets doing? Are they necessary?

Comment: @AlexA.  It is just to keep the structure intact.  When you have a matrix output, this may be more suitable, but in this case it may not be required.  In general, I would do that to avoid any surprises.

Comment: Okay, thanks for explaining! I just tried it and you don't get the right thing without the empty brackets, so I guess they are necessary in this case.

Comment: Also I recommend adding a little explanation in case the OP is unfamiliar with `gsub()`. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @AlexA.  Thanks for suggesting that.  Added some explanation.  As I thought previously, if you don't use `[]` the result will be a list of 2 elements.